Compared to every other type of test, why are unit tests valued so highly?
I am struggling to understand why unit tests are valued so highly in the coding community. If I look at any other type of test (e.g. feature, integration, TIP), I think any of them carry infinitely more value to the project actually "doing what it should do" than unit tests. (To be clear, a unit test for me is testing against the smallest scopes of a codebase, i.e. functions like isPrime or hasThisValue, etc.; something like "GetUserData" is not a unit test, but rather a feature or behavior of the actual software.)
For example with feature tests, let's say I have 100% feature test coverage  - meaning subtests cover every single scenario for a given feature (e.g. "Add a user"). Why would I ever write unit tests now? I don't understand why they would be important if I can already guarantee that my feature completely works. And even in the scenario in which we add more features (e.g. "Change user", "Delete user", etc.), I would just reuse the existing functions that I wrote for "Add user", e.g. getString. If getString doesn't work properly, then I would just adjust it so that it does, and then rerun all feature tests again and make sure that "Add user" obviously still works. Maybe it's just the way I code, but I've always felt as though this "adjustment" has never been a large issue (if it was even necessary).
I've read some other arguments which state that it's easier to find bugs, but I would argue that if I have already covered every single scenario in subtests of my feature test, then where is this bug supposed to come from? This scenario (e.g. with "Add a user" that a certain symbol isn't allowed) should have been covered by a subtest of the feature test (e.g. "TestDontAllowThisWeirdSymbol").
With all that said, I do completely agree that unit tests have their purpose - however, in comparison to other types of tests, in my opinion they are just "nice to have" and nowhere close to being mandatory.

If you have 100% feature test coverage that includes every possible test scenario and you have complete confidence that any error will cause at least one test to fail and everything passing means your code is ready to ship, then maybe you don't need unit tests. But does that suite also run quickly enough that you can run it regularly enough that it's useful? If one or more feature tests fail, is it actually easy to tie that back to "oh getString needs fixing"? Are they reasonably readable, or full of long repetitive setup? That's where you might want something lower level.

Unit tests may not be "valued" so much as they are "available." Developers write unit tests as they go, often as part of the development process before what they're testing actually works. So they tend to become canonical tests for a project because they're created early and often vs integration tests which rely on a more complete product. And, since devs are lazy(in a good way) those tests which exist will be considered more important than those which still need to be written.

Essentially, Unit Tests are used to identify defects related to safety, security, and reliability. They are pretty good ways to find vulnerabilities in each little part of code, and then help you fix them.
Seeing as you have 100% feature test coverage, you don't need unit tests, but it can help you detect small vulnerabilities or maybe some redundant sections of code. With that though, if some of your feature tests do fail, unit tests would tie into that and help you find exactly what failed and where
Happy coding and hope this helped!
